# How to quit '1Password Agent' on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos

I have [1Password](http://agilewebsolutions.com/products/1Password) installed on my MacBook, and I'd like to quit the '1PasswordAgent' process (starts at ~login) that I see in the Activity Monitor, and which I wish to remove when playing a game, but the problem is that whenever I quit this process it just returns with a new PID a moment later.

Does anyone know of some way to remove this process?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I made another user account and 1PasswordAgent does not run for that user, which I think is the best solution for my situation, because it will handle all similar situations with other programs.

Answer (score 6):

Just remove the file `~/Library/LaunchAgents/ws.agile.1PasswordAgent.plist` and reboot the machine.

(Maybe there's the same file in `/Library/LaunchAgents/ws.agile.1PasswordAgent.plist`)

EDIT : You can use [Lingon](http://lingon.sourceforge.net/) (now discontinued, but the latest version still works) to check every startup services.

Answer (score 5):

Open Terminal, then ask `launchd` to stop it:

```
$ launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/ws.agile.1PasswordAgent.plist
```

That will immediately stop the 1Password agent, but won't prevent it from starting again on the next boot. If you want that, add `-w` to the command:

```
$ launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/ws.agile.1PasswordAgent.plist
```

To re-enable it without rebooting, substitute `load` for `unload` in those commands.

If `/Library/LaunchAgents/ws.agile.1PasswordAgent.plist` also exists — as it does on my system — you might have to repeat those commands for that file, too.

---

Regarding Lingon (recommended in another answer) beware that the current version has moved to the Mac App Store, and as a result of the MAS sandboxing policies, it can no longer modify system-level services. Since the 1Password agent seems to install `launchd` entries at both the user and system level, it might work for this, and it might not.

Comment: `launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/ws.agile.1PasswordAgent.plist` would also disable it permanently.

Comment: Thanks, @LauriRanta. I've incorporated that into the answer.

Comment: 2019 update:  1Password's launchctl plist is not longer in that directory

Answer (score 4):

Please refer to this article [Completely Uninstalling 1Password](http://help.agile.ws/1Password/uninstall.html)

Comment: You don't have to uninstall 1Password to get this to happen.

Answer (score 1):

The method recommended by an AgileBits staff member in [this thread](https://discussions.agilebits.com/discussion/90667/cant-close-1password-7-osx-10-13-4) is to:
1) Search for 1Password in the finder so you can open it. This will make the 1Password menu visible [image: 1Password menu bar].

2) Click on the name "1Password" to open that menu. It will look like 
[image: like this] with the last option being "Quit 1Password". Don't click that yet.

2) Hold down the Control (^) and Option (⌥) keys. This will change the last option to "Quit 1Password Completely" [image: Quit 1Password completely]. Now select this option.